# How to get values for a dynamically generated array in php

Tags: php

I am generating a dictionary in PHP where key and values are added to the dictionary.

But I am not able to fetch the values back. I am using following code:

```
    //some code here
    while (($line = fgets($fileServices)) !== false) {
            //echo $line.'....................';
            if (strpos($line,'header') == false){
                    $serviceName=explode(",", $line)[0];
                    $RestartData=explode(",", $line)[1];
                    $StatusData=explode(",", $line)[2];
                    $serviceRestartMappingdict[$totalServices]= $serviceName.':'.$RestartData;
                    $serviceStatusMappingdict[$totalServices]= $serviceName.'_'.$StatusData;
                    $totalServices = $totalServices+1;
            }
    }
    $counter=0;
    //echo $serviceStatusMappingdict[0];
    fclose($fileServices);

    $counter=0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($serviceStatusMappingdict); ++$i){
            echo '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<'.$serviceStatusMappingdict[$i].'>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>';
    }
```

If I do an echo like `echo $serviceStatusMappingdict[0];`, I get the value but when I use a loop to access the data I do not get any value.

Comment: what is the result of `echo $serviceStatusMappingdict[1];` ?

Comment: It gives me element at 1

Comment: `print_r ($serviceStatusMappingdict);` so we can help you

Comment: It gives me: ( [0] => kakfa_ps -ef | grep kafka | grep server.properties [1] => zookeeper_ps -ef | grep zookeeper | grep zookeeper.properties [2] => schemaregistry_ps -ef | grep schema-registry | grep java [3] => influx_/sbin/service influxdb status | grep active | grep running [4] => mysql_/sbin/service mysql status | grep active | grep running [5] => cassandra_/sbin/service cassandra status | grep active | grep exited [6] => aerospike_/sbin/service aerospike status | grep active | grep running )

Comment: :( it really should work, i don't understaind where is the issue... please try with this code and show me the result
`print 'Type: ' . gettype($serviceStatusMappingdict)  . "\n" ;
 print 'Count: ' . count($serviceStatusMappingdict)  . "\n\n";
 foreach ($serviceStatusMappingdict as $key => $value) {
  echo gettype ($key) . "\n";
  echo $value   . "\n";
  echo $serviceStatusMappingdict[$key] . "\n\n";
 }`

Comment: Here is the data: Type: array Count: 8 integer kakfa_ps -ef | grep kafka | grep server.properties kakfa_ps -ef | grep kafka | grep server.properties integer zookeeper_ps -ef | grep zookeeper | grep zookeeper.properties zookeeper_ps -ef | grep zookeeper | grep zookeeper.properties

Comment: I have not posted all the data since it was over the limit of comment

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT] The problem is coming because of the '<' character. Get rid of them and it will work straight away

To answer the following comments that have appeared, the characters '<' and '>' in combination in html refer to an opening and closure of a tag. ex: `<div>`

The problem comes because the browser is trying intrepreting it as an unknow element and does not know what to do with it. If you inspect the html code of the page you'll be able to see that the information is actually there, just not properly rendered.

Comment: The code is already available. It is just that i did not add it to the code snippet above

Comment: What do you get if you `print_r($serviceStatusMappingdict)` ?

Comment: It gives me: ( [0] => kakfa_ps -ef | grep kafka | grep server.properties [1] => zookeeper_ps -ef | grep zookeeper | grep zookeeper.properties [2] => schemaregistry_ps -ef | grep schema-registry | grep java [3] => influx_/sbin/service influxdb status | grep active | grep running [4] => mysql_/sbin/service mysql status | grep active | grep running [5] => cassandra_/sbin/service cassandra status | grep active | grep exited [6] => aerospike_/sbin/service aerospike status | grep active | grep running )

Comment: The problem is comming because of th  '<' character. Get rid of them and it will work straight away.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT] Following Umpert parial answer, I tried this and it does the expected behavior. Can we have more informations on why it does not work in your case :

```
<?php

 $array = array( '0' => "kakfa_ps -ef | grep kafka | grep server.properties",
            '1' => "zookeeper_ps -ef | grep zookeeper | grep zookeeper.properties",
            '2' => "schemaregistry_ps -ef | grep schema-registry | grep java",
            '3' => "influx_/sbin/service influxdb status | grep active | grep running",
            '4' => "mysql_/sbin/service mysql status | grep active | grep running",
            '5' => "cassandra_/sbin/service cassandra status | grep active | grep exited",
            '6' => "aerospike_/sbin/service aerospike status | grep active | grep running");
for($i=0;$i<count($array);++$i){
  echo '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<'.$array[$i].'>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>';
}
 ?>
```

Same amount of '<' and '>' as in your OP. Just to make sure.

Comment: This one seems to be working... i have just added commas to separate data: kakfa_ps -ef | grep kafka | grep server.properties ,,,,,,,,zookeeper_ps -ef | grep zookeeper | grep zookeeper.properties ,,,,,,,,schemaregistry_ps -ef | grep schema-registry | grep java ,,,,,,,,influx_/sbin/service influxdb status | grep active | grep running ,,,,,,,,mysql_/sbin/service mysql status | grep active | grep running ,,,,,,,,cassandra_/sbin/service cassandra status | grep active | grep exited ,,,,,,,,aerospike_/sbin/service aerospike status | grep active | grep running  Count : 6

Comment: Well.. And the code snippet that you gave us is exactly what it is in your program ? Nothing is in the middle of this ?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing in between.

Comment: @AmandeepSingh can you ask Umpert for an explanation ? I would really like to know ! :)

Comment: @AmandeepSingh updated my post with a question. I don't think I'll be able to focus on my work without the answer to all this. :P

Comment: @AmandeepSingh Also, if I may, could you reword your question and title to know why the '<' characters cause problem. That would be a more unique question and a much better one. :)